# CCextractor CUI can't be reached

Tags: windows, web

I am developing a website with the help of ccextractor, but can't figure out how I get to use the ccextractor CUI on my windows local machine.

I have gone through all the documentation but can't figure it out please help!

I've gone through all the documentation but can't figure it out